# Can Magmi skip invalid data during import?

Tags: csv, magento, format, magmi, automated-deployment

Hi i am using magmi to import the products from vendor csv.
It has been automated that then csv is copied from the vendor site to my site through ftp_get php function.
The problem is there is some invalid data in the csv which magmi cant process and it stucks at particular point .

When i manually open the file in excel and save and than upload than it process properly. 
Can it be possible that Magmi can skip the invalid row

Comment: How can i import images for my multi-store, can i get csv header column values,, my csv : https://snag.gy/e3kioC.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you know the row numberyou could use the Magmi Import Limiter

http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Magmi_Import_Limiter

Or, I have written my own front end client interface for Magmi, this would also give you plenty of options on what data each run should proccess.

http://thenorthernfoundry.com/magmi-client-download/

Comment: How can i import images for my multi-store, can i get csv header column values,, my csv : https://snag.gy/e3kioC.jpg